# Filter validation-type in Html.ValidationMessageFor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I got a model like this:

```
public class SignUpModel
{
    [Required, DisplayName(@"Particulars/Salutation")]
    public short Salutation { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<SalutationOption> SalutationOptions { get; set; }

    [Required, DisplayName("Particulars/FirstName")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Required, Display(Name = "Particulars/LastName")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [Required, DataType(DataType.EmailAddress), Display(Name = "Particulars/Email")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required, DataType(DataType.EmailAddress), Compare("Email"), Display(Name = "Particulars/EmailConfirmation")]
    public string EmailConfirmation { get; set; }
}
```

Now in my view, I want to post validation-errors (also client-side) using `@Html.ValidationMessageFor`.

```
<div class="section-field">
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Email, new { @class = "control-label required" })
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Email, new { htmlAttributes = new { autocomplete = "off" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x=>x.Email);
    </div>
</div>
<div class="section-field">
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EmailConfirmation, new { @class = "control-label required" })
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.EmailConfirmation, new { htmlAttributes = new { autocomplete = "off" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x=>x.EmailConfirmation);
    </div>
</div>
```

But in `Html.ValidationMessageFor` I only want to show things like "invalid email-adress" or "both emails must match".

I don't want to show the message saying, that the fields are required, since all are required - and they get bordered red.

Is it possible somehow? Tried with implementing a custom HtmlHelper, but that doesn't filter anything client-side.

Comment: Have you tried `[Required(ErrorMessage = "Your Custom Message")]`?

Comment: @Izzy yes, thats not the point. I just want to filter them out on validating to not show them - not changing the error-message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I fixed it simply with css now.

I add a class `required-validation` to invalid `Required`-validations:

```html
<p class="validation-error required-validation">The field 'FirstName' is required</p>
```

and added into my `custom.css`

```css
p.validation-error.required-validation {
  display: none;
}
```

Other ideas on how to handle this with ASP are welcome :)